# Winform style issue: Windows classics style?

Tags: .net, user-interface, coding-style, winforms

In one application I'm suddenly getting a style that looks like windows classics.

It looks good in the Visual Studio designer (left on the image) but when I run the application it looks like windows classics style (right on the image) and I can't find it.

I tried to create a new clean window and add one button to it and that also looks like windows classics.

Any ideas for how to fix it or what I can search for to find whats causing it?

[image]

Comment: Do other programs on your computer (like calc) look like classic Windows theme?

Comment: No. Just tried the calculator and it looks super fine!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do my forms look like 'Windows Classic'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466282/why-do-my-forms-look-like-windows-classic)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to call `Application.EnableVisualStyles ();` in you Main method.

Comment: And make sure to do so before you create any windows or start the message pump.

Answer (score 1):

Nice!
Looks like it's supposed to now:

[image]

Comment: Although old, you should actually add this as a comment to @Foxfire's answer