# Why do my forms look like 'Windows Classic'?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, skin

Is there any free tool to style my C# Windows Forms, to make them look like Windows 7 Windows.

`**EDIT**`

In the designer mode, I have this :

[image]

But when I run I get this :

[image]

I don't know why I get that. (Old style)

Thanks

Comment: I don't care for your -1 sir, so if you have something to say, just say it.

Comment: There is one [non-free tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/what-is) around. (-1 isn't mine)

Comment: aren't they (WinForms) being "skinned" by default depending on user's Windows Version? Or do you want them to look like Win7 in, for example, WinXP?

Comment: I'm so confused, because I'm running the APP in Win 7, but I get the old windows style

Comment: nice screenshots, i gave you +1, you deserve it for not letting WinForms die ( :

Comment: Thanks, but you know why I'm getting this in output !!

Comment: This doesn't deserve down votes, but the question should be rephrased to be something like: Why do my forms look like 'Windows Classic'?

Comment: +1 Always try to ask clear questions

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should enable visual styles

look [Application.EnableVisualStyles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx)

Call this method before creating any controls

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new YourMainForm());
}
```

Comment: God knows why this isn't the default! :)

Comment: @Jacob... I thought that was the default for a winforms app... I could be wrong though :)

Comment: Maybe it is default when building stuff in Visual Studio, but I was building with WinForms using Python for .NET and couldn't figure this out! Thank you :)